# I can't install Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 11

Tags: boot, 18.04, 22.04, tearing

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 11, but it cannot be done. There are errors showing up, but when I tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 it's working.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install WSL or in bare metal?

Comment: Can you successfully boot from the live USB?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card. Did you mean 22.04? Did you try Safe Boot? And then choose restricted extras when installing to get correct video driver. Is UEFI Secure Boot on?

Comment: I’m not talking about the wsl. Its about the dual boot. When i first installed 22.04 on windows 11 pc , everything was normal. Later i had to uninstall it to re install 18.04 . I deleted the partitions and i also deleted the grub bootloader through cmd prompt. When i try to boot with the usb which has the 18.02 image. A black screen with distorted messages come up.